# What are your opinions on methods of function storage and execution in PHP?

Tags: php, function

So far in my career as PHP programmer, I have stored my functions statically in class separated PHP files by topic (such as "database", "htmlfunctions" etc). I recently had the idea of storing all my PHP functions in separate files and executing them by calling the include function in the appropriate spot, or including them on a need-to-use basis.
That would have the advantage of ridding me of the need to include a bunch of references and keeping track of which functions are in which files. In addition, I would be able to call functions from the address bar.
Parameters would be redundant since (from what I know) the include function copy/pastes file content directly and un-compiled into it's place. The included files would then be able to use local and global variables.

What are your thoughts and comments on this, experts?

Comment: Definitely have a look at PHP's [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php): It takes your approach even further.

Comment: This looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought is, that you might want to have a look into [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and the [PHP class autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) features. Using global variables in your application without any level of encapsulation doesn't sound like a good practice anymore.